# IIS Configuration to connect Tomcat server using httpplatformhandler add on

Tags: tomcat, iis, httpplatformhandler

Iam trying to configure IIS using httpplatformhandler add on to connect Tomcat server where my Java application deployed by referring below link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/windows-server-azure-pack/mt125371(v=technet.10)

However, I am not succeeded to connect tomcat. below is my web.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<location path="AdminSuperTrustedSite" overrideMode="Allow">
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="httpplatformhandler" path="*" verb="*" modules="httpPlatformHandler" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <httpPlatform processPath="C:\tools\apache-tomcat-10.0.12\bin\startup.bat" arguments="start" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile="\\?C:\tools\log.txt">
      <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="JRE_HOME" value="%programfiles%\java\jdk1.8.0_202" />
        <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_HOME" value="C:\tools\apache-tomcat-10.0.12" />
        <environmentVariable name="CATALINA_OPTS" value="-Dport.http=%HTTP_PLATFORM_PORT%" />
        <environmentVariable name="JAVA_OPTS" value="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" />
      </environmentVariables>
    </httpPlatform>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I updated below attribute in Tomcat Server.xml

```
<Server port="-1" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
<Connector port="${port.http}" protocol="HTTP/1.1">
```

I am always getting below error

HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.

I enabled directory browsing option and then it is trying to list out directory instead showing application.

Can anybody help me to find out what could be the issue ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need `<location path="AdminSuperTrustedSite" overrideMode="Allow">`? And what is the URL that gives you 403.14? Seeing 403.14 indicates that URL was not handled by HttpPlatformHandler (due to misconfiguration).

Comment: I use to get error  HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.   Hence I added the location tag avoid this error.   
 http://localhost/ is URL I am using to browse the application since I am using default website. what will be URL I must use ? I tried all possible way with localhost context but it did not work.

Comment: So the actual error to fix is that 500.19, not anything else. Remove any unnecessary changes (like the location part) and reproduce the 500.19 error page. Edit the question to include that exact page.

Comment: For 500.19-Internal Server Error errors, you can refer to this link: [HTTP Error 500.19 - internal server error when you open an IIS Webpage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/iis/http-error-500-19-webpage).

Comment: I corrected these errors. Now getting HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway
There was a connection error while trying to route the request.

Comment: Try to use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.